# Clicking in a dropdown with scroll in Capybara

Tags: automated-tests, capybara, selectize.js

I'm having a problem with my dropdown, It uses selectize to make the dropdown, but when the number of options is too big it adds a scroll to the dropdown and when I try to click in some option that is not seen (that you need to scroll it to see) the capybara thinks the option is there and click out of the input where the option would be without scrolling. There's nothing changing the visibility (ordering it to search for not visible elements don' work either)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can click a visible element in drop-down than send the `:arrow_down` native key to simulate down key action. You should do this until the element visible, then click the `active` option.

Check this for [selectize.js](http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) home page:

```
find("#select-country-selectized").click()
while(true)
  break if find(".option.active").text == "Benin"
  find("#select-country-selectized").native.send_keys(:arrow_down)
end

find(".option.active").click
```

Comment: edit for the first option. There should be always `.option.active` if not there is problem with `click`

Answer (score 0):

The example of gunesmes was very helpfull, I made some changes like making the break one line up because otherwhise it would always jump the first option and changing the find for has_css? because find returns an error and has_css? returns true or false. I also changed the first find because I use cocoon and I need always to fill the last input generated. The final result was like this:

```
    def scroll_dropdown(user)
     all('input[id$="_user_id-selectized"]').last.click
     while(true)
      break if page.has_css?(".option.active", text: user, match: :prefer_exact, wait: false)
      all('input[id$="_user_id-selectized"]').last.native.send_keys(:arrow_down)
     end

     find(".option.active").click
    end
```